# Conditionally extract and change the date in date field

Tags: r, regex, if-statement, lubridate

I've a dataframe as follows:

```
season  date
9090-2019fall   1/1/00
9879-2018fall   2/2/01
9801-2018spring 3/3/03
7868-2017fall   4/4/04
5765-2020fall   5/5/05
```

```
library(tidyverse)
my_data <- tribble(~season, ~date,
                   '9090-2019fall', '1/1/00',
                   '9879-2018fall', '2/2/01',
                   '9801-2018spring',   '3/3/03',
                   '7868-2017fall', '4/4/04',
                   '5765-2020fall', '5/5/05')
```

I'm tying to extract the year from the season column and then change the date in the date column where year < todays year.

The new date should be the first day in the month of may for the extracted year.

I came across a solution to do it manually for each year.

This is where I've gotten so far:

```
df$date<-ifelse(grepl('2019fall', df$season, paste0('2019-05-01'),df$date)
```

Is there a way to have it run it in a loop instead of doing it manually?

My expected result is as follows:

```
season  date
9090-2019fall   5/1/19
9879-2018fall   5/1/18
9801-2018spring 3/3/03
7868-2017fall   5/1/17
5765-2020fall   5/5/05
```

Comment: why output of row 3 is not changed to `5/1/18` even when 2018 < 2019.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of ways of solving this.  Here I've used created an intermediate column of years to make the logic clear.  Change this to suite your needs.  Also consider converting the character representation of date into an object of class Date which represents calendar dates.  See `?as.Date`

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)

my_data %>% 
mutate(year = as.numeric(str_sub(season,6,9))) %>%  # Extract the year
mutate(date = case_when(
                        year < 2019 ~ str_c('5/1/', year),
                        TRUE ~ date)) %>% 
select(season, date)

# A tibble: 5 x 2
#  season          date    
#  <chr>           <chr>   
# 1 9090-2019fall   1/1/00  
# 2 9879-2018fall   5/1/2018
# 3 9801-2018spring 5/1/2018
# 4 7868-2017fall   5/1/2017
# 5 5765-2020fall   5/5/05
```